# Get all columns by eager loading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

I created a table with relation with `ApplicationUser` and when I want to get with eager-loading, I could not get all columns from that table my search base on user authentication.

```
var UserSites = await _SqldbContext.Users
                                   .Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                                   .Include(x => x.sites)
                                   .ToListAsync() ;
return Json(UserSites);
```

But in return I only get one row of that table with two columns

```
[{"sites":[{"id":1,"userId":"c0e8be95-535c-449c-9aa1-06702cd4c983"
```

but I have more rows with this `userId` and also here I get only two columns but I have more than two columns, I am not sure what is wrong here please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ToListAsync() works properly and If you make break point you may see all data from your site but here I think Json does not show it properly, instead of start from User table in your example I started with your proposed table name sites (to get all data of this table)

```
 var UserSites = await _SqldbContext.sites.Include(x => x.[Name Of User in relation table]).Where(y=>y.[Name Of User in relation table].UserName== User.Identity.Name)
                .ToListAsync();


        List<sites> siteObject=new List<sites>();

        UserSites.ForEach(x =>
        {
            sites site = new sites() {
            // fill property of your class
            };

            siteObject.Add(site);
        });


        return Json(siteObject);
```

I hope this code works for you.